# Limit graph range on first load

Tags: dygraphs

Is there a way to set the graph time range to a fixed time range (24 hours) when the graph first loads?  I can change the range using buttons that call a javascript function and use the dateWindow option.  I have tried "window.onload" at the beginning as well as the end of the page that is loaded but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dateWindow`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#dateWindow) option in the constructor to do this:

```js
var nowMs = new Date().getTime();

new Dygraph(div, data, {
    dateWindow: [nowMs - 24*60*60*1000, nowMs]
});
```